# Placing Docusign Checbox in PDF document generated via conga

Tags: docusignapi

I am generating a document using conga and document outcome is pdf document and sending to the customer to be signed via DocuSign integration (Docusign for salesforce- DocuSign version7.4.4). But have the requirement to put checkboxes in the document before sending, so that customer can give consent and acknowledge and then sign.

Please suggest using DocuSign how this can be automated?

Comment: Please provide more information by EDITING your question. Please add info on how are you sending the generated PDF to DocuSign? Via DocuSign for Salesforce? (Which specific version?) Via some other method? Manually?

Comment: @LarryK I have updated the question also, sending generated pdf using DocuSign integration (Docusign for salesforce- DocuSign version7.4.4).

Answer (score 0):

You  need to create a document custom field in DocuSign,  if You “checkbox” and then make the anchor with the {r}.  Example /yes{r}/. Now, in the composer document, you can just add /yes1/ for recipient 1 in the Composer template.

Hope that makes sense.